# Classes and code throwing errors and strange unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a tiny project. And I am running into some issues, I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now. But, I finally decided to come to SO, and post this here. I am trying to get two of my functions to work properly:

`Remove(...)` and `SearchWithName(...)`, I am using the C++ Range-based for loops. But, the Remove doesn't delete the pointer of Employee in Array. I get some memory thrown error. And for some reason, even if names match, or don't match I still get matched. Strange. I am trying to make it partially match or full match.

HERE's THE CODE: https://onlinegdb.com/B1Whf_eUP

```
int main(){
    
    EmployeeArray* empArr = new EmployeeArray[2]
    {
        Employee("Richard Johnson", "1801 E 10th St Pueblo, CO 81001"),
        Employee("David Paras", "15 Spring St Rear Peabody, MA 01960"),
    }
    
    std::cout << (empArr->SearchWithName("lol") != NULL ? "Employee found!" : "This employee couldn't be found!") << std::endl;
    
    empArr->remove(*(Employee("Richard Johnson", "1801 E 10th St Pueblo, CO 81001"))));
    
    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR:**

**/usr/sbin/ld: /tmp/ccOVptof.o: in function `main': jdoodle.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to` Employee::Employee(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)'
/usr/sbin/ld: jdoodle.cpp:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `Employee::Employee(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: please explain what you observed not only your interpretation. "Remove doesn't delete the pointer of Employee in Array" why do you think so? What is the output and what is expected output?

Comment: Those aren't "range-based for loops", they are classic loops

Comment: @Alix Blaine This delete ee; does not make a sense. You do not have an array of pointers.

Comment: somehow you assume that the entries in the array that are left after removing one are always in the front, but what if you delete the first entry? Then you cannot iterate the first `current_total` entries to get all non deleted

Comment: nothing is removed because your code does not compile. Please include the error message in the question

Comment: there are several typos in your code. I cannot know it, but it looks like the code you posted is not your real code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: btw use a `std::vector<Employee>` and most of your problems will be gone

Comment: You can't remove an array element, whether with `delete` or any other method.

Comment: memory leak alert. `employees` is not deleted in a destructor.

Comment: why did you remove most of your code? Questions about code should contain a [mcve] in the question

Comment: See link! Above. That's shy!

Comment: links can break thats why code should be in the question, and coincidentally I was not able to open it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What's the compiler error

You did not define `Employee(std::string name, std::string address)`. You only declared that. `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>` may look bogus, you may just treat it another name of `std::string`.

#### What would happen to your code if it compiles

Your `EmployeeArray::employee` is pointing to a dynamically allocated array:

```
employee --> +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | E | E | E | E | E | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

And when you do the for loop and found the employee to delete, your `ee` looks like this:

```
employee --> +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | E | E | E | E | E | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
                   ^
                   |
                   ee
```

You may expect the `Employee` the `ee` points to being deleted, with other elements shifted front.

However, `delete`ing such a pointer does not make sense. C++ array is almost dumb, not as smart as you may think. In fact what you made is an *undefined behaviour* in C++, according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete):

> - `::(optional)    delete    expression`  (1)
> - `::(optional)    delete[]  expression`  (2)
>
> 1. Destroys one non-array object created by a new-expression
> 2. Destroys an array created by a new[]-expression
>
> For the first (non-array) form, expression must be a pointer to an object type or a class type contextually implicitly convertible to such pointer, and its value must be either null or pointer to a non-array object created by a new-expression, or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array object created by a new-expression. If expression is anything else, including if it is a pointer obtained by the array form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.
>
> For the second (array) form, expression must be a null pointer value or a pointer value previously obtained by an array form of new-expression. If expression is anything else, including if it's a pointer obtained by the non-array form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

C++ compiler will treat your `delete` as an attempt to destroy the `Employee` the `ee` points to, and de-allocate memory of that `Employee`. Since your `EmployeeArray::employee` is not created by a single `new`, but an element of array created by `new[]`, `delete` may not successfully destroy the object and de-allocate the memory.

And *undefined behavior* means anything could happen if you do so. You may see errors, see exceptions, see core dumps, see no error but get wrong result, or everything works fine without bothering. Thus *undefined behavior* is extremely hard to debug, and should be avoided with every effort.

#### Solution

If you insist using `new[]` to manually create array, you may use `new Employee*[]` to create an array of pointer. Then you assign manually to each pointer with `Employee`s created with `new Employee()`. That will be like

```
employee --> +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
             | P | P | P | P | P | ... |
             +---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

And you'll be able to `delete` a single element (Still, you need to shift the leftover pointers left manually, `delete` will not handle this for you).

#### Non-answer answer

Instead of handling dirty memory stuffs, you may use `std::vector` to store your data, and use `std::find_if`/`std::remove_if` for data manipulations.

To elegantly remove elements in `std` containers, you may use `std::remove_if` + `std::vector::erase` combination. [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-container-in-c/) is an example.

Comment: i had the first impression that "Non answer answer" is the title for the whole answer. Maybe move that to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, `std::erase_if` is C++20. Before compilers and users get accustomed to new standard, we'll be using `remove_if`+`vector::erase` combination for sometime. @JHBonarius